# The Dold-Lashof construction and the Milnor filtration

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This question regards Section 3.5 of the book *Secondary Cohomology Operations*  by John R. Harper.

In Subsection 3.5.4, the author considers a surjection $f: X\times Y\to X$ of topological spaces, and defined, for the above $f$, the Dold-Lashof construction
$$DL(X) = X\bigcup_f (CX\times Y)$$
where $CX$ denotes the unreduced cone of $X$ with $\{0\}\times X$ collapsing to a point and $[1,x,y]$ identified with $f(x,y)$.

Apparantly this notation is ambiguous as it does not reflect the map $f$ which is part of the definition of $DL(X)$.

This causes some confusion later on around Proposition 3.5.1 where the Milnor filtration is established. The author states that for a simply connected space $Y$, we can "iterate" the Dold-Lashof construction to obatain a sequence of inclusions of spaces

$$ * = B_0(Y) \hookrightarrow B_1(Y)\hookrightarrow\cdots\hookrightarrow B_k(Y)\hookrightarrow\cdots$$

such that $B_0(Y)$ is a point, $B_1(Y)\simeq\Sigma\Omega Y$, $B_{k+1}(Y) = DL(B_k(Y))$ and the colimit of the sequence is $Y$.

Apparantly, we need a space $Z_k$ and a map $f_k: B_k(Y)\times Z_k\to B_k(Y)$ to define $DL(B_k(Y))$, but what are they?

Comment: You don't need to introduce spaces $Z_k$. If you like, you can take $Z_k$ to be a single point for each $k$, a consequence of explicitly stating the initial data to consist of the map $\Omega^*Y\rightarrow\ast$. The space $B_{k+1}$ is just the mapping cone of the iteratively produced map $p_k:E_l\Omega Y\rightarrow B_k$.

Comment: @Tyone If that is the case, then I get $B_1(Y) = DL(B_0(Y)) = DL(*)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: $B_1Y$ is the mapping cone of $p=p_0:\Omega Y\rightarrow \ast$, which is $\Sigma\Omega Y$, as I said above.